# Setting logging config file for Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, eclipse-juno

To specify my logging configuration file I currently need to set the VM arguments separately for each *run configuration* in my current Eclipse project:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=src/main/resources/logging.properties
```

I know I can also set this globally for the workspace by going to

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java / Installed JREs,
```

selecting the appropriate JRE, clicking "Edit..." and adding that line to the "Default VM arguments" field.

But is it possible to set this as the default per project (instead of workspace or run configuration)?

Comment: your question solved my problem! how to set the logging configuration in just one place

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles across this as I did, you can specify VM arguments by run configuration by right clicking your project, selecting run as -> run configurations and switching to the arguments tab. Then just put in -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/your/file/path/here

Comment: But then it's per run configuration, not per project, right?